# Cannot send Shippment Email using PHP - Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email, shipment-tracking

I have a script to create shipments using PHP code.

I have everything working but I am not able to send Shipment emails to customers. See it says `(the shipment email is not sent)` ... I always have to press `Send Tracking Information` button to send emails, and then it starts showing `(the shipment email was sent)`

[image]

This is my complete code.

```
Mage::init();
$comment = null;
$email = true;
$includeComment = true;

$orderId = $data[5];  //get ordernumber from csv

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

if ($order->getId()) {

    $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();

    if ($order->getShipmentsCollection()->getData()) {
        echo 'Debug 1<br>';
        foreach ($order->getShipmentsCollection() as $shipment) {
            $shipmentid = $shipment->getId();
            echo 'Debug 2 ' . $shipmentid . '<br>';

            $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentid);
            $trackdata = array();
            $trackdata['carrier_code'] = $data[22];  //get CARRIER_NAME from csv
            $trackdata['title'] = $data[22];    //get title from csv
            $trackdata['number'] = $data[20];       //get CONSIGNMENT_NO from csv

            $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($trackdata);
            $shipment->addTrack($track);
            $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                    ->addObject($shipment)
                    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                    ->save();

            $shipment->sendEmail(true, '');
            $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
        }
    } else {

        $convertor = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_order');
        $shipment = $convertor->toShipment($order);

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
            if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                continue;
            }
            $item = $convertor->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem);
            $qty = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
            $item->setQty($qty);
            $shipment->addItem($item);
        }

        $trackdata = array();
        $trackdata['carrier_code'] = $data[22];  //get carrier_code from csv
        $trackdata['title'] = $data[22];    //get title from csv
        $trackdata['number'] = $data[20];       //get track number from csv     
        $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($trackdata);
        $shipment->addTrack($track);

        $shipment->register();
        $shipment->addComment($comment, $email && $includeComment);

        $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($shipment)
                ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                ->save();

        $shipment->sendEmail(true, '');
        $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
    }


    $order->addStatusHistoryComment("My comment why the status was changed", Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    $order->save();

    echo "<br /><br />Shipment Tracking Number Updated For the Order Id {$orderId} Successfully";

} else {
    echo 'Order with ID ' . $orderId . ' does not exists in magento <br>';
}
```

You can see the

```
$shipment->sendEmail(true, '');
$shipment->setEmailSent(true);
```

part of code but its not working.

Where I am going wrong? I have `Magento ver. 1.9.2.4`